# Map two lists using Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-3

I need to map the Fields of My Class to RegisterNewPeopleCommand, but in the third field (passed parameter) I must pass a List of Phones (List ) that is inside the PeopleViewModel class (PeopleViewModel.PeopleListPhones). I need to convert from List  to List . How do I do that? Should I use any loopback or other feature?

```
CreateMap<PeopleViewModel, RegisterNewPeopleCommand>()
    .ConstructUsing(p => new RegisterNewPeopleCommand(p.Id, p.Name, p.PeopleListPhones //I need to convert this List <Phone ViewModel> property to List <Phone Model>)

));

public abstract class RegisterNewPeopleCommand(int id, string name, List<PhoneModel> phonesModel)
{
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
    PhonesNumber = phonesModel;
}

public class PhoneModel()
{
    public int PhoneId
    public string Number
}

public class Phone()
{
    public int PhoneId
    public string Number
}
```

Comment: Did you use ProjectTo? http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: I did not use it ... it's that my project uses the DDD concept ...

Comment: Try [constructor mapping](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html).

Comment: In the tutorial does not teach how to work with Lists. I could not adapt it from list to list :(